# How to use an imported table data in a calculation of f[x,y,z], where each row of the column correspond to x,y,z?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, list-manipulation

I have a table with desired inputs of a given function `efvc[n,m,u]`. I want to calculate for different values of `n`, `m` and `u`. I imported a Excel table with the values I want. Is there a way to call each row of the table as `n`,`m`,`u` inputs on `efvc`?

```
{{{0., 0., 6.}, {0.104716, 0.0000884874, 6.}, {0.206578, 0.000825568, 
6.}, {0.301571, 0.000365564, 6.}, {0.410605, 0.0000384834, 
6.}, {0.506678, 0.0000494736, 6.}, {0.610588, 0.000617136, 
6.}, {0.707025, 0.0000728179, 6.}, {0.80244, 0.0000829668, 
6.}, {0.905712, 0.00125702, 6.}, {0.994287, 0.0046171, 6.}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {{{0., 0., 6.}, {0.104716, 0.0000884874, 6.}, {0.206578, 
     0.000825568, 6.}, {0.301571, 0.000365564, 6.}, {0.410605, 
     0.0000384834, 6.}, {0.506678, 0.0000494736, 6.}, {0.610588, 
     0.000617136, 6.}, {0.707025, 0.0000728179, 6.}, {0.80244, 
     0.0000829668, 6.}, {0.905712, 0.00125702, 6.}, {0.994287, 
     0.0046171, 6.}}};
```

You can [`Apply (@@@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) `efvc` on level 1 of `data[[1]]`:

```
efvc @@@ data[[1]] // Short
```

> {efvc[0., 0., 6.], efvc[0.104716, 0.0000884874, 6.], << 8 >>,  efvc[0.994287, 0.0046171, 6.]}

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also add a new definition for your function to make processing easier:

```
efvc[{n_, m_, u_}] := efvc[n, m, u]
```

then it becomes a simple mapping:

```
efvc /@ data[[1]]
```

or

```
Map[efvc, data, {2}]
```